# Resume event fired Android 6 devices for the permission dialog

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have an ionic app 1.3.2, using cordova-android 5.2.2

On Android Marshmallow v6, why does the `resume` event get fired after I tap on Deny or Accept Android permissions on marshallow 6 devices?

I would think `resume` is reserved only for when you really 'minimise' the app, and then properly resume it, not for when a dialog pops up. Is there any way to distinguish between a proper resume and a system permission dialog resume?